# Visual Studio C# delay function for if statment

Tags: c#, time, delay

I'm looking for a way to create a delay in my code without stopping the rest of the code in this time frame. It has to work as follows. If a condition is true for X amount of seconds, set the alarm bool High. The code below is a part of code where I set the alarms but there needs to be a delay.

I'm very new to C# so try to dumb it down a bit, maybe a small example or links.

```cs
if (Valve.Parameter.NormallyOpen == false) 
{
    if (Valve.Status.Output == true & Valve.Status.Opened == false)
    {
        Valve.Alarm.NotOpened = true;
    }

    if (Valve.Status.Output == false & Valve.Status.Closed == false)
    {
        Valve.Alarm.NotClosed = true;
    }
}
```

Some background info: this will be a valve control block in PLCNext written in C#. The control block should give a alarm if the valve is send open but does not give open feedback within X seconds (takes time to open).

```
 using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Iec61131Lib;
using Iec61131.Engineering.Prototypes.Types;
using Iec61131.Engineering.Prototypes.Variables;
using Iec61131.Engineering.Prototypes.Methods;
using Iec61131.Engineering.Prototypes.Common;

namespace EclrFirmwareLibrary1
{
    [FunctionBlock]
    public class Valve_Test
    {
        [InOut]
        public Valve Valve;

        [Output]
        public bool Output;

        double seconds = 1.00; // 1 Second Interval
        

        [Initialization]
        public void __Init()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Initialize the variables of the function block here
            //
        }
        
        [Execution]
        public void __Process()
        {
            Valve.Status.Interlock = Valve.Control.Interlock;
            Valve.Status.Opened = Valve.Control.FB_Open;
            Valve.Status.Closed = Valve.Control.FB_Closed;
            
            if (Valve.Control.Manual_Mode == true){
                Valve.Status.Manual_Mode = true;
                Valve.Status.Auto_Mode = false;
            }
            if (Valve.Control.Auto_Mode == true & Valve.Control.Manual_Mode == false){
                Valve.Status.Manual_Mode = false;
                Valve.Status.Auto_Mode = true;
            }

            if(Valve.Status.Interlock == false & Valve.Alarm.General == false)
            {
                if (Valve.Status.Manual_Mode & Valve.Control.Manual_Control)
                {
                    Output = true;
                    Valve.Status.Output = true;
                }
                else if (Valve.Status.Auto_Mode & Valve.Control.Auto_Control)
                {
                    Output = true;
                    Valve.Status.Output = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Output = false;
                    Valve.Status.Output = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Output = false;
                Valve.Status.Output = false;
            }

            //Alarms---------------------------------------------------
            var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
            var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);

            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
            {
                CheckValve();
            }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);

        }
         
        private void CheckValve()
        {
            if (Valve.Parameter.NormallyOpen == false)
            {
                if (Valve.Status.Output == true & Valve.Status.Opened == false)
                {
                    Valve.Alarm.NotOpened = true;
                }

                if (Valve.Status.Output == false & Valve.Status.Closed == false)
                {
                    Valve.Alarm.NotClosed = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Valve.Status.Output == false & Valve.Status.Opened == false)
                {
                    Valve.Alarm.NotOpened = true;
                }
                if (Valve.Status.Output == true & Valve.Status.Closed == false)
                {
                    Valve.Alarm.NotClosed = true;
                }
            }
            
            if (Valve.Status.Opened == true & Valve.Status.Closed == true)
            {
                Valve.Alarm.OpenedAndClosed = true;
            }


            if (Valve.Alarm.NotClosed || Valve.Alarm.NotOpened || Valve.Alarm.OpenedAndClosed)
            {
                Valve.Alarm.General = true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: C# and Visual Basic are two different languages. First get clear which one you're using. The code sample you're showing appears to be C#.

Comment: I'd expect to see a `polling-like` method, because statuses and everything can change over time you need to repeat your checks. Then in such method you can simply increment counter and when counter exceed certain value - show error.

Comment: I don't know what you've done, but you need to create a task, or you can create events

Comment: Its C# I got visual studio an visual basic mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to note in this case is that the device you are using includes a .NET runtime implementation that is a subset and specialisation of the complete .NET runtime. This "eCLR" (Embedded CLR) is designed to operate in the deterministic real-time context required for many industrial control applications.

The details of this implementation can be seen in the [PLCnext Info Center](https://www.plcnext.help/te/Programming/Csharp/Csharp_in_PLCnext.htm)

When you create a PLCnext C# project in Visual Studio, the project includes a Programming Reference (.chm file). You will see from this reference that the Timer class is not included in the eCLR.

To your question:

There are a number of ways you can implement a delay function in a PLCnext C# function. Perhaps the simplest is to use the `DateTime.Now` property to get the current system time when the alarm condition is first seen, and remember this value. Then, on each call to the `Process` method, you can compare the current time to the time when the alarm condition was first seen. When the time period exceeds the preset time, then the output is set.

For more help with questions related to PLCnext Control devices, you can visit the [PLCnext Community](https://www.plcnext-community.net/en/). There is an active forum there, where you can discuss these sorts of issues with other PLCnext users.

Answer (score 0):

To call a method each x seconds you can use the TimeSpan Method provided by C# and just pass a method called CheckValve, where you put all your code into.

**TimeSpan Example:**

```cs
double seconds = 1.00; // 1 Second Interval
var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);

var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
{
    CheckValve();   
}, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
```

---

**I would also advise you to refactor some of your code:**

You can replace bool == true checks with just the bool and bool == false checks with just the bool and a ! before the name.

I would also add an else if so if the if is true you don't need to check the other statement.

**CheckValve Method:**

```cs
private void CheckValve() {
    if (!Valve.Parameter.NormallyOpen) {
        if (Valve.Status.Output && !Valve.Status.Opened) {
            Valve.Alarm.NotOpened = true;
        }
        else if (!Valve.Status.Output && !Valve.Status.Closed)
        {
            Valve.Alarm.NotClosed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
I'm having trouble with this one it says timer is not part if System threading.
What could be the reason?

Comment: It should work, try to add using System.Threading; on top of your file

Comment: I already did that but it isn't available when I type System.Threading.Timer

Comment: What happens if you just type new Timer?

Comment: The only thing that pops up is TimerCallback.

Comment: did you include using System; the code works for me.

Comment: I added the Code to the post. In Visual studio i get a error on the "var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>" line. 

Error = The type or namespace name 'Timer' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Threading' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: var timer = new Timer((e) =>{ .........} should work. Especially because you included System and System.Threading

Comment: Strange. Still says the same. It's like System is outdated or something.